# How do characters in Naruto train to use elemental jutsus besides the wind nature?

Tags: naruto

We already know how Naruto trained to use his element. But how do others train to use fire, water, and earth elemental jutsus? Do they burn a leaf and then burn a waterfall? Do they suck the water in the leaf out and then try and move a waterfall? Was there any explanation for chakra natures that wasn't Naruto's?

Answer (score 1):

There were other episodes that explains better how the different chakras works, specially in the original Naruto. Obviously the training would be very different for others elements.

**Here are some references**

> Naruto chapter 321, pages 4-5
>   Naruto chapter 315, page 13 
>   Thir dDatabook, page 236
>   Naruto chapter 315, page 15 
>   Third Databook, page 214 
>   Naruto chapter 375, page 11
>   Fourth Databook, page 249
>   Naruto chapter 689, page 5 
>   Naruto chapter 316, page 9
>   Naruto chapter 207,page 8
>   Naruto chapter 316, pages 4-7
>   Naruto: Shippūden episode 55 
>   Naruto chapter 361, page 13
>   Third Databook, pages 274-275

The way to understand how elements works would be understanding their properties, because it explains a lot about the compatibility and the way for creating new techniques.

Simple examples of training for other elements are creating a wall, cut or broke things, etc. Techniques that you see in one element could be imitate in another, but the difference you'll see it in a battle.